# Communication between local database and centralized database

Tags: .net

I have to develop a C# .net windows application for a client.The             database is SQL Server.Our client has 18 offices in various countries.This desktop application will be instlled in all offices.There will be local database in all 18 offices and also there will be centralized database.

My questions are given below.

1) How can we move data from branch server to central server and also from central server to branch server?

2)How faster and constant connection to database server is achived?
  Also how can we achieve real time updates between all branches and central server?

3)How MSSQL can sync with multiple servers in realtime over the      internet?

4) Can we achieve these things in a place where there is no internet connection?

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com), since it is not programming related, but about setting up a database infrastructure.

Comment: This is a very big subject that can't be answered in a Q&A site. SQL Server supports multiple types of replication (snapshot, merge, transactional) with different tradeoffs on bandwidth, timeliness, processing requirements and the ability to do and propagate local changes to publishers.

Comment: In my scenario which SQL replication type is best?Why(in brief) @Panagiotis Kanavos

Comment: What *is* your scenario? What do you even mean by "real-time"? Replicate changes to all subscribers in 1ms? 1 s? 1m? Are you OK with a 15 min delay? Can you pay for the bandwidth required for faster replication? How often does the data change and how big is the change set? That's why it's impossible to answer this question. You need to consider what are you real requirements and constraints, check the (ample) documentation to understand the tradeoffs and requirements.